# Using shader x, y, z coordinates relative to the tilted object not the scene in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am animating the x,y,z coordinates of vertices in a sphere like manner with horizontal rings around the center as attributes on a THREE.Points() object. It uses a MeshStandardMaterial() and I have then tilted the Points object slightly along the z axis with points.rotation.z = 0.2. Everything is as expected :

[image]

When I swap the MeshStandardMaterial() for ShaderMaterial() and rewrite the animation part into a shader the z tilt has gone. I have checked with an axis helper on the Points object and indeed the object is still tilted but it seems the shader animation is now moving the vertices around the x, y, z coordinates of the scene rather than the tilted Points object.

[image]

As you can see in the picture the sphere and outer ring of particles are no longer tilted on the same angle as the axis helpers.

Is there a quick fix for this or do I have to change the shader animation and factor in an overall rotation there?

Thanks.

Here is the shader script as requested, however I have tested the principle on a few shader animations from various tutorials I have undertaken and they all behave in the same way, so I'm assuming this is an inherent problem or expected behaviour with shaders:

```
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
uniform float uSize;
attribute float aScale;
attribute vec4 aParticle;
uniform float uTime;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main()
{
/**
 * Position
 */
    vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);


/**
* Particle
*/


    float moveT = aParticle.g;

    float moveS = aParticle.r + uTime * aParticle.b;


    float fullRotate = step(360.0, moveS);
    moveS = moveS - (fullRotate * 360.0);


    float radMoveS = moveS * (PI / 180.0);
    float radMoveT = moveT * (PI / 180.0);

    modelPosition.x = aParticle.a * cos(radMoveS) * sin(radMoveT); //x
    modelPosition.y = aParticle.a * cos(radMoveT); //y
    modelPosition.z = aParticle.a * sin(radMoveS) * sin(radMoveT); //z


    vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
    vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;
    gl_Position = projectedPosition;


/**
 * Size
 */
    gl_PointSize = uSize * aScale;
    //Attenuation
    gl_PointSize *= ( 1.0 / - viewPosition.z );

/**
* Color
*/
    vColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Any chance to provide a minimal editable working example, that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: We need to see your shader code. Can't help you without seeing what you're doing wrong. My guess is that you're setting the `gl_Position` without multiplying by `modelMatrix`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the vertex shader code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your vertex shader, you apply the `modelMatrix` to your `position` by multiplication:

```
vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

But then you overwrite any results from that matrix multiplication when you assign each `xyz` component a new value:

```
modelPosition.x = aParticle.a * cos(radMoveS) * sin(radMoveT);
```

This means that what you're seeing is **a.** Not using `position`, and **b.** Not using `modelMatrix`. You simply have to apply the matrix multpilication *after* you've assigned the local vertex positions.

```glsl
vec4 newPosition = vec4(
    aParticle.a * cos(radMoveS) * sin(radMoveT), // x
    aParticle.a * cos(radMoveT), // y
    aParticle.a * sin(radMoveS) * sin(radMoveT), // z
    1.0 // w
);
Vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * newPosition;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution worked. At first with your solution I was getting the z axis tilt but the mirror opposite of what I wanted. When I changed modelPosition to newPosition and then changed modelPosition *= modelMatrix to modelPosition  = modelMatrix * newPosition everything worked! Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops, you’re absolutely right. Matrix multiplication is non-commutative, so order matters. I updated the answer to fix the order.